# Bash script capturing output to terminal

Tags: string, bash, shell

I want to capture into my bash script (in a variable) the output of some command that prints its output to terminal. I have tried the following:

```
TEST_OUT=`the_command ARG1`   #Nope

#Putting the line "the_command ARG1" into a separate script, testing2.sh,

TEST_OUT=$(./testing2.sh)   #Nope

testing2.sh
TEST_OUT=$?  #Nope
```

I am 100% sure that when I run...

```
> the_command ARG1
```

...in a terminal, it prints to the terminal exactly the information I want to capture.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Standard error output does not seem to be captured in your scripts so it will be printed to the terminal.

Comment: If the output is being sent to stderr, you'll need to redirect that to stdout before it can be capture in your var. Try `TEST_OUT=$(the_command ARG1 2>&1)`

Comment: Hey sorry, new to bash and scripting here... Are there 2 ways to print to terminal, stderr and stdout?

Comment: @ShawnChin Oh shit it worked! Nice! Post your answer and I'll accept that

Comment: posted. BTW, you generally print to terminal using stdout and only use stderr for error messages (so it doesn't get hidden when someone redirects the output to a file or var). For quick explanation of stdout and stderr, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the output is being sent to stderr, you'll need to redirect that to stdout before it can be capture in your var. Try:

```
TEST_OUT=$(the_command ARG1 2>&1)
```

Comment: Awesome I didn't know about the difference b/w stderr and stdout. Good stuff.

Comment: If you want *only* stderr, use `$(the_command ARG1 2>&1 >/dev/null)`.